# greatest divisor of a number less than or equal to other number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I want to find  a number $x$, which is divisor of number $n$ such that $x$ is less than or equal to a number $m$.

I just know one approach i.e. try all numbers from $m$ to $1$ and check as if it divides $n$ completely . 
Is there any better algorithm, if yes, then please share.

Comment: Is $m$ also assumed to be a divisor of $n$?

Comment: @amWhy I don't think so because if it was, $m$ would be the answer.

Comment: In response to your response, and assuming $m, n, x \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$.  Than the answer for any $n$ is that x= 1.  You need to give us more information about $m$; otherwise, given your comment above, we can be certain that $x=1$.

Comment: I suspect that, given positive integers $n$ and $m$, you want to find the largest divisor of $n$ that doesn't exceed $m$. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielFischer Now *that* makes sense!

Comment: Via Euclid's algorithm one can very efficiently find the greatest divisor that two numbers have in common without listing all of their divisors. Listing all divisors may be as inefficient as factoring. Might there be a solution to this problem that is as efficient as Euclid's algorithm, or at least more efficient than factoring?

Answer (score 2):

Well, prime factor $n = \prod p_i^{a_i}$ and just test the factors that are less or equal to $m$.

Example: find all factors of $360=2^3\times3^2\times5$ that are less than $27$.

$2^03^05^0=1; 2^13^05^0=2;2^23^05^0=4;2^33^05^0 = 8$;

$2^03^15^0=3;2^13^15^0=6;2^23^15^0=12;2^33^15^0 = 24$;

$2^03^25^0=9;2^13^25^0=18;*\text{stop}*;2^23^25^0=36;$;

$2^03^05^1=5; 2^13^05^1=10;2^23^05^1=20;*\text{stop}*;2^33^05^1=40$;

$2^03^15^1=15;*\text{stop}*;2^13^15^0=30;$;

$*\text{stop}*2^03^25^1=45;$

So $1,2,4,8,3,6,12,24,9,18,5,10,20,15$.

So you don't have to check *all* numbers.  Just the ones that are factors.

===

As per your comment.  Let's suppose we want to find factors of $2^{10}3^{10}5^{10} $ less than $6123$.    We can try to guestimate the highest factor thusly:

The $5$ can be as high $5^5=3125$.  There's "no room" for any factors of $2$ or $3$.  We can replace $5$ with $2*3$, $2^2$ and maybe occasionally$2^3$ and $3^2$.

We can do $5^4=625$ and we can $5^4*3^2;5^4*2*3;5^4*2^3$

$5^3*3^3;5^3*3^2*2^2;5^3*3*2^4;5^3*2^4$

$5^2*3^5;5^2*3^4*2;5^2*3^3*2^3;5^2*3^2*2^4;5^2*3*2^6;5^2*2^7$

$5*3^6;5*3^5*2^4;5*3^4*2^3;5*3^3*2^5;5*3^2*2^7;5*3*2^8;5*2^10$

$3^7*2;3^6*2^3;3^5*2^4;3^4*2^6;3^3*2^8;3^2*2^9;3*2^{10} $

So we just count all the lower powers than those.

That was an extreme example.  If I go back to my 360 and factors less than 27, we can do

$2^3*3$ (and all $2^a3^b ;a\le 3;b\le 1$)

$2^2*5$, $2*3^2$ $3*5$. And all lower powers.

Comment: Answer seems good. Is there no way to do same thing in reverse way i.e. start writing factors in reverse direction which is less than or equal to m?Also is there no intelligent way to write all the factors of a number in decreasing order using its prime factors?  May be some hint can be taken from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ugly-numbers/